# backpack - customizing / changing column display

Tags: laravel

In my controller I am trying format the column display.

For example under protected function `setupListOperation()`, I have

```
CRUD::column('first_name');
CRUD::column('last_name');
CRUD::column('name_format');
```

and depending upon the name_format I will either display first_name + last_name or last_name + first_name

**I tried playing with variables like:**

```
   $display_name = 'first_name' + 'last_name"

$this->crud->addColumn([
        'name' => $display_name,
        'label' => 'Name',
    ]);
```

which does not work.

Questions

1. Do I need to create an override?
2. If not how do I write the code for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using? The class `CRUD` is completely new to me.

Answer (score 0):

First way is to concat two columns in select statement using db raw

```
Solution 1:

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $users = User::select("*", DB::raw("CONCAT(users.first_name,' ',users.last_name) as full_name"))
        ->get();
  
    return view('home', compact('users'));
}
```

Use:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)

    {{ $user->full_name }}

@endforeach
```

The second way is to use laravel model eloquent scope, using scope to concat two columns.

Solution 2:

You need to set scope in your model like as we defining on user model.

```
<?php
  
namespace App;
  
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
  
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
   
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password','type','is_active',
    ];
   
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
   
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
   
    /**
    * Get the user's full concatenated name.
    * -- Must postfix the word 'Attribute' to the function name
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
    }
  
}
```

Use:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)

    {{ $user->full_name }}

@endforeach
```

Use Pluck Concat Two Columns:

```
$users = User::select("id", DB::raw("CONCAT(users.first_name,' ',users.last_name) as full_name"))
        ->pluck('full_name', 'id');
  
dd($users);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define mutator method in your crud model to get full name
like that:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute(){
  return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
}
```

then you need to add this attribute as column in your crud

```
CRUD::column('full_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use type `closure` column and return html which will be displayed in the cell:

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
    'label' => 'Full name',
    'type' => 'closure',
    'function' => function($entry) {
        $full_name = $entry->first_name . ' ' . $entry->last_name;
        return "<span style='color: blue'>{$full_name}</span>";
    }
]);
```